# R Coding - Adding a vector

Tags: r

I am fairly new to R coding and am trying to create a function that will add a vector to the existing data frame.

I have a data frame with 5,049 rows and two vectors as shown below:

```
Name <- Jane Tom Harry ...  Anna

Counter <- 1 2 3 4 ... 5049
```

I would like to create another vector, say SET, that slits the data frame by 100 rows. For example `SET = 1` for `Counter = 1 to 100`, `SET = 2 for Counter = 101 to 200`, etc... So, here `SET` will have values `1,2,3, ... 50`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use integer division:

```
counter <- 1:5049
SET <- ((counter - 1L) %/% 100L) + 1
```